# Inno Setup - How to keep registry keys after uninstall

Tags: registry, key, inno-setup, uninstallation

I am have an installer running for a shareware program that has a time limit. The installer saves an obscure key in the windows registry with the install date, and I do not want this key to be removed when uninstalling, so that the user cannot simply uninstall and reinstall the program in order to circumvent the time limit.

I have tried to use custom Delphi code to write the key ( RegWriteStringValue() ) but it looks like the uninstaller removes those as well. Any ideas on how to keep the registry key (or another way to keep the original install date in the system)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Inno Setup [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp) ([[Registry] section](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm)):

> By default, registry keys and values
>   created by Setup are not deleted at
>   uninstall time. If you want the
>   uninstaller to delete keys or values,
>   you must include one of the
>   uninsdelete* flags described below.

Comment: You are correct! I must have had that flag on by mistake. Thank you!